# What's the relationship between Google's Rubik's cube doodle and the word "Google"?

Tags: google-doodles

Normally a Google doodle is a doodle that represents the company logo, or the word "Google". I believe it is true also for today's Rubik's Cube doodle. Before you click on the doodle, there is a cube with few colors rotating. **How is it related to "Google"?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about gaming.

Comment: I think other than the game itself, it's another puzzle Google posted to the public.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please forgive my handwriting.

[image]

Note that the colours match up with the colours of the letters in the normal logo.